# making Login Identity View in an independent Layout in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to make a login view independent from the Default _Layout (like any proper app) . 
i have achieved to make the login as default view  using

```
 options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
```

My problem is i want to make the /accout/login as the default view with out the _layout page . 
so i go to areas/identity/pages/_ViewStart.cshtml and changed the Layout from

```
"/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; to "/Views/Account/Login";
```

the problem is that the controller render to account/login . but i can only see the button register and login [image] as shown in the attached image . 
So can any one guide me how to make a login as independent view ?

Comment: How did you create this project? For `areas/identity/pages/_ViewStart.cshtml`, it's Razor Page project, but for your screen shot, there is `AccountController` which seems you use identity controller. A mini demo to reproduce your issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass any reference to a Layout page by setting the reference to null in your .cshtml page.

Your code would look like this `@{ Layout = null; }`.

By setting Layout to null your .cshtml page is no longer rendered into a parent layout, i.e., partial views are no longer partials.

Keep in mind that once you remove the Layout reference, any css styles etc. will no longer apply.

In your sample code, it looks like you are still pointing to _loginPartial.cshtml which just shows either register + login OR applicationUser link + logout option. What happens when you click on the login button??

Comment: it does nothing